# C# - Access field of a base class

Tags: c#

I have a base and derived class wherein I have a boolean variable in the base class. Now when checking the variable in the derived class, the value of the boolean variable is always False.

```
public class RainingQuestion
{
    public virtual bool raining { get; set; }
    public virtual string Answer(int elementToTest)
    {

        if (elementToTest < 176)
        {
            raining = false;
            return ("It's not raining.");
        }
        else
        {
            raining = true;
            return ("It's raining.");
        }
    }
}


 public class WindSpeedQuestion : RainingQuestion
    {
        public override bool raining { get; set; }
        public override string Answer(int elementToTest)
        {
            //bool _raining = this.raining;

            if (elementToTest > 15)
            {
                if (!raining)
                {
                    return("You can fly your kite. Wind speed is at " + elementToTest + "kph.");
                }
                else
                {
                    return("Don't fly your kite. It's raining.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return("Don't fly kite. Wind Speed not strong. Wind speed is at " + elementToTest + "kph.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
RainingQuestion ques1 = new RainingQuestion();
WindSpeedQuestion ques3 = new WindSpeedQuestion();

Console.WriteLine(ques1.Answer(180));
Console.WriteLine(ques3.Answer(16));
```

In this example, ques3.Answer must supposed to return "Don't fly your kite. It's raining" because the raining variable in the ques1 is true and the given parameter in ques3 is more than 15 but the boolean variable in ques3 always returns False.

May I know what I can be missing?

Comment: Are you sure that your example code is correct? I think "public override string Answer(int elementToTest)" in your base class (RainingQuestion) should read "public virtual string Answer(int elementToTest)" - or it won't compile. Can you change your post to show exactly how raining is always false?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I follow you, but. ques1 and quest3 are different "instances" so they are completely unrelated.

Comment: sorry, raining question has a base class which I removed in the code, yes should be marked virtual

Comment: Try playing with setting "ques3.raining = true;" and see what it does. Also, if you are using an IDE, drop a "breakpoint" in your code, and have a look at the "state" of the raining variable using the "Watch" windows - it will help you understand and learn what's going on.

Comment: ques3.raining = ques1.raining did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `ques1` and `ques3` are different instances of the classes.

You're setting `raining = true;` in ques1 in the first `Answer()` call, but ques3 is a completely different object to ques1 and so the raining will be false since in ques3 you've never set it.

Think of it like in real life. Say you have two pencils. One in your left hand and one in the right hand. Both of them are pencils, but they're different objects. The pencil in your left hand can be sharp while the pencil in your right hand isn't. The left could be blue and the right red. Sharpening the Right pencil more, won't make the left one any sharper.

In your code, the lines

```
    RainingQuestion ques1 = new RainingQuestion();
    WindSpeedQuestion ques3 = new WindSpeedQuestion();
```

mean that you're creating two different versions of an object. Any changes to ques1 aren't going to affect ques3 because like the pencils in each hand they're different things.

Answer (score 1):

You override both (raining and Answer) in your derived class and you did't call the base class implementation.
so :
1 - remove this line in your derived class

```
public override bool raining { get; set; }
```

2- call base.Answer in your derived class Answer method like this :

```
public override string Answer(int elementToTest)
{
    base.Answer(elementToTest);

    if (elementToTest > 15)
    {
        if (!raining)
        {
            // and so on
```

Comment: elementToTest value in derived class is different from base class

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it by setting the value of the raining variable in ques3 to be the same as with ques1

```
RainingQuestion ques1 = new RainingQuestion();
RainingQuestion ques3 = new WindSpeedQuestion();

Console.WriteLine(ques1.Answer(180));
ques3.raining = ques1.raining; //this did the trick
Console.WriteLine(ques3.Answer(16));
```

Comment: This is the same answer as @tropher - but his explains why this works. You should accept his answer.